# how to open a socket in php

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

I am completely new to sockets and not that familiar with the concept. I am planning on making a phone application for chatting. now I was told that if you open a socket you can push results (chat entries) to the phone application.

now is this something I can do with fsockopen php function?? and how would I keep the connection open and push data from the database to the application?

Thanks

Comment: And what exactly is the problem looking up Sockets in the PHP Manual? Or googling for a PHP Sockets tutorial? Have you actually tried anything before asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) and you'll be up and running in no time. Socket servers are mysterious and fun... :D

Comment: I expected a minimal socket example as an answer. RTFM is always a good thing for students and such, but stackoverflow is also for people wanting to quickly copy/paste snippets instead of spending 5 minutes of doc reading each and every time.